# mysql-workbench not starting. Error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: mysql, linux

trying to start mysql-workbench, i get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do i fix this?

Notes:

- I have added the MySQL APT Repository
- mysql-client is installed.

Comment: If you installed it from the deb package, run `sudo apt -f install` after it.

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

On debian Wheezy.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```